# Python sqlite - insert if not exists

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database table `place` like below:

```
command_create_table = """CREATE TABLE if not exists place (
name VARCHAR(100),
lat DOUBLE(100, 10),
lng DOUBLE(100,10),
vicinity VARCHAR(100),
typeOfPlace VARCHAR(100));""
```

I want to insert into this table only if certain entry doesn't exist. But there is no such command like below.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT if not exists into place (name, lat, lng, vicinity, typeOfPlace) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(name, lat, lng, vicinity, typeOfPlace))
```

I tried making `name` as `PRIMARY KEY` in the `place` table and using command

```
cursor.execute("INSERT into place (name, lat, lng, vicinity, typeOfPlace) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(name, lat, lng, vicinity, typeOfPlace))
```

But getting error `sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: place.name`

What am I missing? Any suggestion?

Comment: are you inserting twice the same `name` value?

Comment: `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO...`

Comment: Actually, yeah, you've not set any unique constraints on the table fields.

Comment: @roganjosh yes INSERT or IGNORE INTO .. is the answer. Add it as answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what that statement does if you don't set any constraints when you create that table. I think it might be grossly inefficient and I'm currently on a phone so can't test properly. I'll hold back from an answer for now. It's open to all to answer :)